# How to load an HDF5 file that has wrong datatype flag?

Tags: python, matlab, hdf5

I have an `.h5 file` that I can read with Matlab, IDL, and python. However, both Matlab and python load this file but the Dataset gets a Datatype `H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)`. Basically I have values of floating point that get converted to integer in the reading process, making values like 0.1 into just 0.

Reading with IDL somehow ignores the internal flags in `HDF5` file and gives me proper values.

Is there a way in Matlab or python to force read HDF5 file Datasets with double precision?

In Matlab I do:

```
hinfo = hdf5info('./data.h5');
dset = hdf5read(hinfo.GroupHierarchy.Groups(1).Groups(1).Datasets(1));
```

In python:

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File('./data.h5', 'r')
dset = f['entry']['data']['data']
```

Comment: can you show the code you are using to import the file?

Comment: added the codes

Comment: What makes you think this is a double precision? According to HDF Group docs, H5T_STD_U16LE is an unsigned short integer. Have your tried to open and view with `HDFView` or dump file schema with `h5dump`?

Comment: If you're open to another Python option, you can try this with pytables: `import tables as tb` ;
`h5f = tb.open_file('./data.h5', 'r')` ;
`dset = h5f.get_node('/entry/data/data').read()` ; semicolons separate code lines above. `dset` returned is a numpy recarray, similar to h5py

Comment: this is actually exactly the problem: the dataset inside of the HDF5 file IS in double precision, but both the Matlab and python HDF5 readers load it in unsigned integer (thus loosing info after the coma). I assume that this is because the writer of HDF5 file has wrongly set the Dataset type flag. What I'm puzzled is why there is no standard way to read the HDF5 file without looking at the Datatype in the metadata of the file. Also HDFView fails to do that. Only IDL was able to ignore the Datatype and load it in full precision. I haven't tried the h5dump, will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: You have an interesting predicament. How was the HDF5 file created (to have double precision data and yet the data type is set to  unsigned integer - very strange)? I don't think it was creaetd with h5py or pytables, as the datatypes for each field are defined with a numpy dtype object, or take from the dtypes of the numpy object used to create the table. And, as you have observed, both h5py and pytables inherit the field datatype from the dataset definition in the HDF5 file.

Comment: As a workaround, you can try creating a numpy arrray with the dtypes you want, then read the data from the file. Not sure how h5py or pytables will handle this. They may give an error on the mismatched dtypes. Or they may just extract the data, and let you deal with the consequences. It's worth a try.

Comment: you are right, the data was not created with h5py or pytables. it was created with EPICS plugin called [areaDetector Plugin NDFileHDF5](http://cars.uchicago.edu/software/epics/NDFileHDF5.html). I think the plugin dumps the data as is into the Dataset, and then the metadata is grabbed separately from the field "# of data bits" which by default is set to 8 ([here](http://cars.uchicago.edu/software/epics/NDFileHDF5.png) is the picture).

Comment: I tried creating the numpy array with the proper datatype and then read the file into it, but it just converted 0 to 0.0. I think both the Matlab and python are wrapped around the cpp codes from HDF5 group. So the reading of the data takes the data in the way it was specified in the reader. While the IDL reinterprets the datatype on loading. I was really hoping that there is a way to load HDF5 data ignoring the metadata..

Answer (score 0):

### Reinterpreting the data in Numpy

At first make sure that you know the actual datatype. You wrote float, but you have to know the exact datatype (float64, float32, float16) and the order (Little, BigEndian).

**Interpreting float64 to uint16 and back**

```
import numpy as np
#copy the dset using np.copy()
#The following should be quite straight forward
A=np.ones(2)
print(A)
#Interpret the data as np.uint16
B=np.frombuffer(A,dtype=np.uint16)
print(B)
#Make the reverse
C=np.frombuffer(B,dtype=np.float64)
print(C)

[1. 1.]
[    0     0     0 16368     0     0     0 16368]
[1. 1.]
```